# Como colocar as tagas ''a'' no canto do banner?

Tags: html, css

Quero colocar agendar o horário e contato no canto direito do banner e está assim :
https://prnt.sc/1gnnx6b

codigo:

```css
.banner {
  background-image: url(../img/banner-barbearia.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 55rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.bannerTitulo {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 4.5rem;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.bannerP {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  margin: 0;
}

.botaoBanner {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<section class="bannerBarbearia">
  <div class="banner">
    <h1 class="bannerTitulo">Transformando homens em astros</h1>
    <p class="bannerP"> A experiência completa da melhor barbearia de Curitiba.</p>
    <p class="bannerP">A melhor versão da sua barba e cabelo</p>
    <div class="botaoBanner">
      <a href="#" class="botaoAgendar">Agendar horário</a>
      <a href="#" class="botaoContato">Contato</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Não entendi a pergunta, poderia ser mais claro? Se achar que ajuda a explicar coloque uma imagem do resultado que pretende obter

Comment: Seria essa a referência do design :https://prnt.sc/1go84vi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que percebi você quer alinhar os `<a>` à direita. Faltava você definir uma width para o ''container'' dos botões. Inseri `width: 100%`

```css
.banner {
  background-image: url(../img/banner-barbearia.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 55rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.bannerTitulo {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 4.5rem;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.bannerP {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  margin: 0;
}

.botaoBanner {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="bannerBarbearia">
  <div class="banner">
    <h1 class="bannerTitulo">Transformando homens em astros</h1>
    <p class="bannerP"> A experiência completa da melhor barbearia de Curitiba.</p>
    <p class="bannerP">A melhor versão da sua barba e cabelo</p>
    <div class="botaoBanner">
      <a href="#" class="botaoAgendar">Agendar horário</a>
      <a href="#" class="botaoContato">Contato</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Obrigado por me responder ! Não tava conseguindo enxergar isso